# Should I Inform the interviewer that I have already joined somewhere, but still considering them before the final onsite round?

Tags: interviewing, salary, new-job, ethics, probation

I have joined a new company while the interview process was going on for the other company. The other company is located in a foreign country, so the interview process took some time. They have arranged a final onsite interview with all the arrangements in their country after three weeks (flight tickets, hotel rooms etc.).

It has been two weeks since I joined the new company and the work here doesn't seem very challenging in terms of technology. So, I am still open to the other opportunity.

During the interview, I didn't get a chance to tell the company I had switched jobs. I had a final discussion about my current salary and I told them the salary I was getting in the previous company.

Should I explicitly tell the employer, by setting up a call, about my company changing, before the final round?

After analyzing the compensation I would require, given what I am getting now balanced by the expense ratio of the countries, it would be quite high and I have a doubt if the company would accommodate that. Should I ask for a discussion over the salary range and compensation they might offer?

PS: Irrespective of the result of the interview, I would want to take it as an experience, as I have very little experience in giving interviews in foreign countries. On the other hand, I don't want to surprise the other company, at a very late stage, where all their money and time spent on me would be wasted.

Comment: I always say what salary I want, never what I have. It's irrelevant what I'm currently on because there may be other reasons it's lower or higher than the salary on offer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I explicitly tell the employer, by setting up a call, about my company changing, before the final round?

No, I wouldn't tell this employer about starting a new job in the last two weeks. This makes you look disloyal and a flight risk. Most companies want to invest in candidates that will stay at least 2 years, especially international ones, due to cost of visa sponsorship and relocation.

> After analyzing the compensation I would require, given what I am getting now balanced by the expense ratio of the countries, it would be quite high and I have a doubt if the company would accommodate that. Should I ask for a discussion over the salary range and compensation they might offer?

Yes, you should definitely reach an agreement about salary range. When you do this depends on your negotiation strategy. To some people, they won't even consider interviewing for a company unless the salary range is discussed upfront. Others, like myself, deliberately not offer a number until the interview has completed. Given you may want to consider this interview purely for the experience, I recommend negotiating your salary during or after the onsite interview.

> I had a final discussion about my current salary and I told them the salary I was getting in the previous company.

Typically, you should not discuss your current salary. If you are underpaid for your experience and position, revealing your current salary greatly limits your negotiation power. In some areas such as the state of California, it is illegal to ask a candidate their current salary.

Comment: Thanks @jcmack for your reply. In that case should I bring up the offer(current new company) I have during negotiation to justify the salary I am asking for?

Comment: @Shimona You can bring up the competing offer during your negotiation unless the language of the offer letter stipulates that you do not share this information. However, because this is technically your current salary, you should be free to discuss it if you are based in the United States. But I'm not lawyer and this isn't legal advice.